# Unity plugin android native camera

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, camera

I wrote a android plugin for processing camera preview and turn the flash on, but then I found out that for some inexplicable reason plugin does not work properly on some smartphones. That is not the flash is activated and not called handler preview. 
Even on different smartphones from one version of Android (4.1.3) plugin behaves differently..
what could be the causes of bug? where do dig? 
Please help :(

Comment: In order for people to answer your question, you'll probably need to provide more detail on how the plugin behaves differently on different versions.

Comment: Do not turn on the flash and not called handler preview. And no errors have been reported.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many diffirent Camera versions and variations on Android its quite difficult to debug. However you could try and go through some of the existing plugins for using the Camera - Camera Capture Kit for Unity is a support for turning on the flash/torch and is tested on a large array of Android phones and works on both iOS and Android.